# DuplicateIdException - myfaces 3.02, primefaces 13.0.0, TomEE 9.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, myfaces

I have a page with two forms. When an ajax call is made to the backing bean to update text in the calling form, myfaces DuplicateIdException is thrown. When the web socket tag is removed, the form updates as expected.

Looking at the stack trace, the problem appears to be in the myfaces state saving algorithm, but I have zero knowledge in this area.

Any clue how to remedy and still use websocket client?

Thank you

Form 1: <f:websocket> form (because the production application uses a websocket for push notifications)

Form 2: Display for file downloads using Primefaces DataView or Facelets repeat and attempting to do an ajax update on the form. (the DuplicateIdException is identical whether using <p:dataView  or <ui:repeat)

Environment: TomEE 9.1, Jakartaee-api 9.1, JSF Apache MyFaces 3.0.2, PrimeFaces 13.0.0, OmniFaces 4.2

The stack trace:

```
    SEVERE: Component with duplicate id "j_id__v_6" found. The first component is {Component-Path : [Class: jakarta.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /test-pages/test-dup-ids.xhtml][Class: org.apache.myfaces.component.ComponentResourceContainer,Id: jakarta_faces_location_head][Class: jakarta.faces.component.UIOutput,Id: j_id__v_6]}
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.DuplicateIdException: Component with duplicate id "j_id__v_6" found. The first component is {Component-Path : [Class: jakarta.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /test-pages/test-dup-ids.xhtml][Class: org.apache.myfaces.component.ComponentResourceContainer,Id: jakarta_faces_location_head][Class: jakarta.faces.component.UIOutput,Id: j_id__v_6]}
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.createAndQueueException(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:150)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:120)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:120)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.checkIds(CheckDuplicateIdFaceletUtils.java:87)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.DefaultFaceletsStateManagementStrategy.saveView(DefaultFaceletsStateManagementStrategy.java:724)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:213)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1923)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:315)
    at jakarta.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:73)
    at jakarta.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:73)
    at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:166)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:266)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at io.smallrye.metrics.jaxrs.JaxRsMetricsServletFilter.doFilter(JaxRsMetricsServletFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:356)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1762)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

test.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form id="websocket-form">

    <f:websocket id="websocket-0" 
        channel="_pushContext">
        <f:ajax event="updateNotifications" render=":messaging-menu" />
    </f:websocket>

</h:form> 

<h:form id="list-form"> 
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <h2>
            <h:outputText value="#{testBeanDuplicateIds.heading}" />
        </h2>
    </div>
    <ui:repeat var="item" 
            value="#{testBeanDuplicateIds.itemList}">
        <div class="row">
            <p:outputPanel style="text-align:center;">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
            </p:outputPanel>
            <p:outputPanel style="text-align:center;">
                <p:commandButton id="download-button-#{item.id}"
                        onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(startDownload, stopDownload);"
                        value="Download Flyer"
                        ajax="false"
                        >
                        
                    <p:fileDownload id="download-#{item.id}-file-download" 
                            value="#{testBeanDuplicateIds.testFileDownload}"/>
                </p:commandButton> 
                    
                <p:commandButton id="button-#{item.id}-button"
                        actionListener="#{testBeanDuplicateIds.doSomething(item.id)}"
                        value="Do #{item.name}"
                        ajax="true"
                        update="@form">
                </p:commandButton> 
                    
            </p:outputPanel>
        </div>              
    </ui:repeat>    
</h:form>

<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    function startDownload() {
        PF('statusDialog').show();
    }

    function stopDownload() {
        PF('statusDialog').hide();
    }
    //]]>
</script>   

<p:dialog id="status-dialog"
        modal="true" 
        widgetVar="statusDialog" 
        header="Downloading" 
        draggable="false" 
        closable="false"
        resizable="false">
    <i class="pi pi-spinner pi-spin" style="font-size:3rem" />
</p:dialog>
```

TestBeanDuplicateIds.java

```
package com.ui.testbeans;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext;
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBeanDuplicateIds implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private StreamedContent _testFileDownload;

    private ArrayList<Product> _itemList;
    private String _heading;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        _heading = "Testing Duplicate IDs";
        buildTestFileDownload();
        _itemList = new ArrayList<Product>();
        for(int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
        {
            String name = "Item-" + index;
            String description = name + " description";
            Product product =
                    new Product(index, name, description);
            _itemList.add(product);
        }
    }
    
    private void buildTestFileDownload()
    {
        String absolutePath = "/resources/default/testFolder/flyer.pdf";
       
        try
        {
            InputStream inputStream;
            ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            inputStream = externalContext.getResourceAsStream(absolutePath);
            
            _testFileDownload = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                    .name("sample_pdf.pdf")
                    .contentType("application/pdf")
                    .stream(() -> inputStream)
                    .build();
            
            if (inputStream != null)
            {
                inputStream.close();    
            }
            else
            {
                String nullWarning = "InputStream was null!";
                throw new IOException(nullWarning);
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void doSomething(String name)
    {
        System.out.println("Doing: " + name);
        _heading = "Testing " + name;
    }

    public StreamedContent getTestFileDownload()
    {
        return _testFileDownload;
    }

    public void setTestFileDownload(StreamedContent testFileDownload)
    {
        _testFileDownload = testFileDownload;
    }

    public ArrayList<Product> getItemList()
    {
        return _itemList;
    }

    public void setItemList(ArrayList<Product> itemList)
    {
        _itemList = itemList;
    }

    public String getHeading()
    {
        return _heading;
    }

    public void setHeading(String heading)
    {
        _heading = heading;
    }
}
```

Product.java

```
package com.ui.testbeans;


public class Product
{
    private Integer _id;
    private String _name;
    private String _description;
    
    Product(){}
    
    Product(Integer id, String name, String description)
    {
        _id = id;
        _name = name;
        _description = description;
    }   
    
    public Integer getId()
    {
        return _id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return _name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return _description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        _description = description;
    }   
}
```

pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.0</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Any chance you could turn this into a PrimeFaces Test reproducer?  We have a Jakarta version all set up for MyFaces 4.  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test/tree/jakarta

Comment: Thank you. I'll give the test reproducer a look.

Comment: Please boil down a bit further. There's so many noise in the context. Remove PrimeFaces (just replace test code by plain JSF) and check if issue is still reproducible. Remove OmniFaces and check if issue is still reproducible. Replace MyFaces by Mojarra and check if issue is still reproducible.

Comment: Melloware - I was unable to reproduce the behavior with the reproducer. I pushed the changes to https://github.com/tedkspradley/primefaces-test. Loading text.xhtml prints to console "[WARNING] handleException /primefaces-test/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml java.io.IOException: Error in streaming dynamic resource. Verify you are not using a @ViewScoped bean." but the file does download with every second attempt. The offending element in the original scenario appears to be the <p:fileDownload > tag. I've replaced with JSF tags per BalusC and the problem disappears.

Comment: BalusC - Replacing only <p:commandButton> and <p:fileDownload> with <h:commandLink> and JSF download made the function perform as expected. Should I post the updated code in the question? Do you want to make your comment an answer so that I can accept it? Thank you

Comment: Melloware - running profile mvn clean jetty:run -Pmojarra30 was listed at https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test/tree/jakarta, but when I forked from the profile doesn't appear available. When starting primefaces-test with  -Pmojarra30 profile, jetty prints a warning to console: [WARNING] The requested profile "myfaces30" could not be activated because it does not exist.